# How to fix: "Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback()" in a script started by an udev rule

Tags: azure-blob-storage, udev, cffi

When started through cli my python script that uses BlockBlobService located in the package azure.storage.blob runs perfectly, however when started through a udev rule it shows the following message:

```
azure.common.AzureException: Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback().
You might be running on a system that prevents this.
For more information, see https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#callbacks
```

I already checked if some security module like SELinux or PaX could be preventing the memory allocation.

```
user@hostname:~$ getenforce
Disabled
```

```
root@hostname:/# sysctl -a | grep pax
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.br-d8bcb5699c15.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.docker0.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eno1.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eno2.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eno3.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eno4.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp134s0f0.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp134s0f1.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp134s0f2.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp134s0f3.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.veth8b380d4.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.veth94be59b.stable_secret"
```

Looking at BlockBlobStorage code. The exception was raised in the following snippet of the file: azure.storage.common.storageclient.py:

```py
415: logger.error("%s Retry policy did not allow for a retry: "
                  "%s, HTTP status code=%s, Exception=%s.",
                   client_request_id_prefix,
                   timestamp_and_request_id,
                   status_code,
                   exception_str_in_one_line)
     raise ex
```

When looking at the cffi code. The following snippet seems to format the message:
File: cffi/_cffi_backend.c

```c
#ifdef CFFI_TRUST_LIBFFI
    closure = ffi_closure_alloc(sizeof(ffi_closure), &closure_exec);
#else
    closure = cffi_closure_alloc();
    closure_exec = closure;
#endif
    if (closure == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(infotuple);
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_MemoryError,
            "Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback(). "
            "You might be running on a system that prevents this. "
            "For more information, see "
            "https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#callbacks");
        return NULL;
    }
```

How can I make this script run when started by a udev rule?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the above error was because of selinux enhanced security configurations. The error pointed to cffi module which was used by django app. I resolved the error by running the following command. Hope it helps.

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1
```

Make sure to look for the selinux bool settings for the services you intend to use and enable proper configurations. The following command will list available settings for the your service and also tell whether it is on or off :

```
sudo getsebool -a | grep <service>
```